# Conjugation action of $G$ on $N$ induces an action of $G/N$ on $H_{\ast}N$.

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I need some help in proving this result from Weibel or Brown (page $48$ corollary $6.3$).

> If $G$ is a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of it, then the conjugation action of $G$ on $N$ induces an action of $G/N$ on $H_{\ast}N$.

**My Attempt** Now abstractly I think I know how to get an action of $G/N$ on $H_{\ast}N$. Take a $G$-proj. resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ and see it as an $N$-proj. resolution. Clearly, $G$ acts on it, and by definition of $H_*(N)$ we take the $N$ coinvariants, so clearly the action factor through $G/N$.

**BUT**, I really never used the fact that $G$ acts on $N$, nor the preceding result (this result should be an immediate corollary)

> Fix $g_0 \in G$, and let $\alpha \colon G \to G$ be given by $\alpha(g)=g_0gg_0^{-1}$. then $\alpha_* \colon H_*G \to H_*G$ is the identity.

Therefore I feel that I'm overlooking something, in particular I'm not so convinced that taking the $N$-coinvariants with respect to the $G$ action would lead to the canonical action of $G/N$ on the homology.

Therefore **could someone** show me what is this induced action, and where this conjugation and preceding result comes into play in this corollary?

**N.B** This question is clearly related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885081/action-of-g-h-on-h-nhm). The reason why I decided to ask a separate question is that I have specific doubts about its proof , I want some comments on my approach and the linked question is pretty old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was not to construct *some* action, but that specifically the conjugation action gives rise to the action. Choosing a $G$-projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ and viewing it as $N$-projective, you can use the homomorphism $\alpha_{g_0}:N\rightarrow N$ given by $\alpha_{g_0}(n)=g_0ng_0^{-1}$ and the chain map $\tau_{g_0}(x)=g_0x$ as before to obtain a homomorphism $G\rightarrow \text{End}(H_*N)$ and that conjugation by $N$ is the identity on $H_*N$ to get the $G/N$-action.